# C2DM shutdown - what happens if still using C2DM API for GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-manifest, android-c2dm

The long-deprecated Google C2DM push messaging service is being completely shut down as of October 20, 2015.  Does anyone know what will happen in this legacy app scenario?

- Our app server migrated to GCM several years ago
- Our Android app switched to use the GCM sender ID at the same time
- Over 99% of our users are migrated to GCM
- **However**... our Android app still uses the C2DM API internally

  - The `<receiver>` is a C2DMBroadcastReceiver/BroadcastReceiver, not a GcmReceiver
  - The `<service>` is a subclass of C2DMBaseReceiver/IntentService, not GcmListenerService.

So, while this has been working for GCM to date, I'm concerned about what will happen on October 20.  **Will our app still receive GCM messages using the C2DM API?**  I believe it will and that we're OK, but I'd like to be sure.

Of course, we need to complete the migration and update the client code to use the GCM API, and we'll do so.  I'm trying to understand the impact for users who don't update the app to receive this fix.

Comment: If it's being shut down completely, you should expect it to **not** work, come Oct 20th.

Comment: @Andy, on what basis are you making that statement?  Do you have any documentation to point to other than the general C2DM retirement announcement?  The app has been using the old C2DM-style API to talk to a GCM-based server for years now... what exactly would change on 10/20?  Just trying to understand.

Comment: Just the [docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/c2dm). The change that would occur on 10/20 is that **"The C2DM service will be shut down completely on 10/20/2015"**. Currently it's deprecated, but the service is still running, which is why it still works for you. Once it completely shuts down, I think you should be prepared for it not to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Nov 7, 2015 (2.5 weeks after the C2DM shutdown), our app is still able to process GCM messages using the C2DM API.  So, that appears to answer my question.  Thanks for the input.